# How to create machine code from LLVM IR using LLVM C++ API

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to convert LLVM IR to machine code using the C++ API, which I already use to create the IR. Their documentation is a big mess and I didn't found that much help to generate machine code with the API. It sure is explicated but without any example of how to use the classes they provide.

For now I had discovered the TableGen which seems to be the way to go to generate the machine code but no example is provided.

All I have is a complete module, context and builder

```
llvm::Module *module;
llvm::LLVMContext context;
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder;
```

Comment: Machine code for what? Normal x64/ARM or your own custom back end?

Comment: Have you gone over the documentation? You probably need `llc`. However, what does TableGen have to do with what you're writing? Are you targeting a custom/imaginary machine (in which case you need to go over the relevant backend [doc](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html))?

Comment: What I want to do is generating the machine code (an executable) of the LLVM IR generated in the API. I'm trying not to use `llc` or any other compiler/linker for this since LLVM API seems to can deal with the problem (?)

Comment: Look at the ORC APIs, there is a `compiler` class that can generate an object file for you. We could help you better if you also provide the version of LLVM you use.